# visual studio 2017 community - python pandas, win32com

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-2017, pywin32

I've installed VS 2017 community and trying to use win32com and pandas modules. looks like I cannot simply import these for some reason although I believe they should be installed by default as part of the VS.
In VS when I go into view -> other windows -> python environments  and I enter pandas into the search field it is showing there in green. the same goes for pywin32. Therefore I believe I should be good to import them in my python projects - that is not the case however.

Any thoughts how to use these modules with VS 2017 community?

Comment: Are you sure Python interpreter included into VS? In VS2015 there were only PythonTools which is an IDE plugin only, so the interpreter is external to it and it's your choice which Python to use. Interesting if something changed here.